# Getting only zeros my Fortran Runge-Kutta

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Ok, so I'm trying to solve an initial value problem, trying to find the velocity given by the `f` function using Runge-Kutta 2. My program compiles, but when I run it gives me the same value for `v` at any time, but I just can't find where I'm doing it wrong. Could somebody help me?

```
program runge
implicit none

real(8) :: f,t,y,g,v,c1
real(8) a,b,h
real(8) k1,k2,l1,l2,v0,gr,m
integer i,n,j

n=10
a=0
b=100
h=(b-a)/n
gr=9.8100
m=70.0
c1=15.0
v0=20.0
y=0.0

v=v0
t=a

open(1, file="velocidad.txt")
write(1,*) a,v
print*, "       t", "       v"

do i=1,n

    k1 = f(t,v)
    k2 = f(t + h, v + h*k1)
    v = v + h*(k1 + k2)/2
    t = a + i*h

    write(1,*) t, v
    print*, t, v

end do
close(1)

end program runge

real(8) function f(t,y)
  implicit none
  real(8) :: t,y,c1,gr,v,m

  f = -(gr)-((c1/m)*v)

 end function f
```

when I run it i get and output like this:

```
t               v
10.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
20.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
30.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
40.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
50.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
60.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
70.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
80.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
90.000000000000000        20.000000000000000
100.00000000000000        20.000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue lies in your function `f`, specifically in this line:

```
f = -(gr)-((c1/m)*v)
```

The function has its own scope, that is that none of the variables that you have assigned a value to in your main program are accessible to the function, instead it has its own variables `gr`, `c1`, and `m`. Only `t` and `y` are passed to it, but the result of the function is still too small to register any meaningful change in `v`. (When I run your code, the results of `f` are in the order of `-2e-314`, but since you never initialise the variables inside the function, your values may differ.)

As for what you can do:

1. Move the initialisation of `gr`, `c1`, and `m` into the function. These values seem not to change anyway.
2. Move the whole function into the main program, and remove the explicit declaration of `gr`, `c1`, and `m` from the function. That way it will look for the variables in the parent's scope:

   ```
   program runge
       ...
       end do
       close(1)
   contains
       real(8) function f(t, y)
           implicit none
           real(8) :: t, y
           f = -(gr)-((c1/m)*v)
       end function f
   end program runge
   ```

   Note that there is no declaration of `gr`, `c1`, `m`, or `v` inside the function.
3. Put the function and the variables that it depends on into a module:

   ```
   module my_mod
       implicit none
       real(8) gr, c1, m, v
   contains
       real(8) function f(t, y)
           ...
       end function
   end module

   program runge
       use my_mod
       implicit none
       gr = 9.81
       ...
   end program
   ```

   Note that here, there is no declaration of `gr` etc in the main program, as those variables are supplied by the module.

There are a lot of other issues, here are just a few examples:

- Your function has dummy variables `t` and `y` but never actually uses them
- You open a file on unit `1`, which might interfere with other i/o, depending on your compiler. I only use units > 10, or even better, declare a integer for my unit and use `open(newunit=myunit, file=....)` for the open, then read and write with `read(myunit, ...` and `write(myunit, ...`
- Your use of `real(8)` is not compiler independent. Better would be something like this:

  ```
  program runge
      use iso_fortran_env
      implicit none
      real(real64) :: gr
      ...
  ```

But that wasn't the question here, so I'll leave it out.

Comment: In the function being integrated `v` should read as `y`. i.e. `f = -(gr)-((c1/m)*y)`. `v` shouldn't be referenced at all in the function.